# Two ways to install partimage in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 22.04, tar

I have a folder for the program "partimage", and I want to install partimage in Ubuntu 22.04.

The path to this extracted tar file is (I know it is case sensitive):
/Home/Downloads/partimage/partimage-0.6.9.

Inside partimage-0.6.9 are all the files.

No matter how I try, using a path in the terminal, I cannot actually get to an executable file which does indeed install partimage. This includes changing directories to get through "Home" and "Downloads".
Would someone give me an exact path to install this program from the command line (please assume my username is "robin")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Typically a `tar.gz` file will be source code - so are you ready to compile the application yourself?

Comment: "/Home/Downloads/" what is that supposed to be?  I would assume `cd /home/robin/Downloads/partimage/`  to get you to that location

Comment: yes, that is the path that I was hoping would work.

Comment: i followed the "how do i install" protocols, including what you just published in your answer (thank you) (at least as best I could) and could not actually get to a result...hence, my question.

Answer (score 2):

partimage is a partition imaging utility for backing up partitions into a compressed image file. partimage is a mature program that has been in the default Ubuntu repositories for a long time. On the other hand from partimage.org:

> Partimage is no longer an active project. It is recommended to use alternatives such as fsarchiver, partclone, or filesystems tools such as xfsdump.

fsarchiver, partclone and xfsdump are all Ubuntu packages.

To install partimage on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install partimage
```

Comment: From https://www.partimage.org/: "Partimage is no longer an active project. It is recommended to use alternatives such as fsarchiver, partclone, or filesystems tools such as xfsdump." - Partclone is used by [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) which is a small linux operating system to be run 'live' from a USB pendrive in order to clone or create images of a whole drive or one or more partitions (and restore from the image when necessary).

Comment: thank you kindly

Comment: @olivermaz If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.